# Logs not being sent to grafana loki in a docker compose local environment

Tags: docker-compose, grafana, open-telemetry, grafana-loki, open-telemetry-collector

Sending logs to Grafana Loki using the otel-collector

Hi, I am experiencing difficulties getting the logs of my application to show in grafana (grafana loki is running in my local machine using docker compose)

1. my instrumentation configuration

```
logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
            {
                options.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
                options.IncludeScopes = true;
                options.ParseStateValues = true;
                //options.AddConsoleExporter();
                options.AddOtlpExporter(opts =>
                            opts.Endpoint =
                                new Uri("http://localhost:4317"));
            });
```

2. My docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'
networks:
  ragnarok:
services:
  otel-collector:
    container_name: olala-telemetry-otel-collector
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.80.0
    command: [ "--config=/etc/myotel.yaml" ]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-files/myotel.yaml:/etc/myotel.yaml
    ports:
      - "4317" # OTLP gRPC receiver
    networks:
      - ragnarok

  loki:
    container_name:  olala-telemetry-loki
    image: grafana/loki:main-125e168
    command: [ "-config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml" ]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-files/loki.yml:/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "3100"
    networks:
      - ragnarok
  grafana:
    container_name: olala-telemetry-grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:10.0.1-ubuntu
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM=true
    volumes:
      - ./otel-files/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - ./otel-files/grafana/provisioning/datasources:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    networks:
      - ragnarok
```

3. My loki.yml: a shameless copy of the one here https://github.com/Depechie/OpenTelemetryGrafana/blob/main/Docker/loki.yml

I reviewed the configuration a  thousand times, and everything seems correct. But when I hit the local grafana url,
go to explorer section and select loki, it always tell me that there is no data.

I have seen some docker compose examples that use promtail to send the logs, but I understant that the otel collector should take care of that.

At least that was what I tried to configure in the myotel.yaml:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:

exporters:
  loki:
    endpoint: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
    tls:
      insecure: true
  
processors:
  batch:
  attributes/loki:
    actions:
      - action: insert
        key: loki.attribute.labels
        value: RequestPath, dotnet.ilogger.category
service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch, attributes/loki]
      exporters: [loki]
```

Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: Your `myotel.yaml` doesn't have any service pipeline for the logs. Why?

Comment: Sorry, Jan Garaj, I did not think there was a problem with that part of the configuration and I just omitted it when writting the question. I updated the question to display also how the pipeline part is configured

Comment: Do you know the logs are making it to the collector? I.e. have you seen them in the logs on collector.  My first thought is that you don't need the configuration on the OtlpExporter as the configuration you're running should be the default. However, if its making it to the collector, its a loki exporter question.

Comment: Hello Martin, I am not sure how to determine if the logs are making it to the collector, or if the collector is just not sending them to the loki backend. How could I check that? Certainly, in the docker compose console I do not see messages with "collect called" of the type log, so maybe the logs are not been forwarded to the collector, but given the provided configuration why? I am saying the app that the otl exporter endpoint is  http://localhost:4317, and you can see in the yml configuration the collector listening in 4317, and it is up and running.

Comment: You should be able to see from tailing console output of the collector container whether it's receiving data.